# How to test Pulumi S3 bucket event handlers with Mocha in TypeScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mocha.js, pulumi

Recently, I started experimenting with Pulumi and created a basic program that creates an AWS S3 bucket and a lambda function that is invoked on adding objects to the bucket.

```js
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

// Create a simple S3 bucket.
const bucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("testbucket");

// Create a lambda that responds to bucket events
bucket.onObjectCreated("handleObjectAdd", async (event) => {
    // lambda function code
    console.log(event)
});

module.exports = bucket;
```

I tried writing a test in Mocha to test the above code. My test code is as follows.

```js
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import { MockCallArgs } from "@pulumi/pulumi/runtime";

pulumi.runtime.setMocks({
    newResource: function(args: pulumi.runtime.MockResourceArgs): {id: string, state: any} {
        return {
            id: args.inputs.name + "_id",
            state: args.inputs,
        };
    },
    call: function(args: MockCallArgs) {
        return args.inputs;
    },
});

describe("demo tests", function() {
    let bucket: aws.s3.Bucket;

    before(async function() {
        bucket = await import("./index") as aws.s3.Bucket;
    })

    describe("S3 tests", function() {
       it("Lambda handler is invoked on object add", function(done) {
         // PROBLEM: how to implement this
       });
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that I'm clueless on how to test `handleObjectAdd`. I have been searching for a solution for a long time, but couldn't find anything helpful. Can someone provide me with some helpful advice so that I can proceed? Thanks in advance for all the helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this test offers no value. You're effectively trying to test Pulumi internals in your app - which they (presumably) already have done.

Behind the scenes Pulumi does *a lot* of stuff to make the `onObjectCreated` work properly. It serializes the code inside your function callback and transforms it into a Lambda which is a separate piece of cloud infrastructure from the bucket.

After that it has to glue the two together using Lambda Event Source mappings which is an AWS specific implementation that you will also not be able to test using Mocha.

Instead, you should just focusing on writing tests for the actual implementation inside your handler which receives the event. You should just trust that Pulumi will properly create the associated lambda and attach it to the bucket.

If you **really** want to test this you're going to have to do it as an actual e2e test which actually uses real infrastructure. This would involve actually deploying the Pulumi program and then adding items to the bucket and finding some kind of side effect from the handler that you can assert on.

Again though, I strongly recommend that this is not a good use of time or focus as Pulumi should be responsible for ensuring it works as designed and you should focus on your application specific code and behavior.